# How to make a WPF ComboBox to handle click on an overlying TextBlock?

Tags: wpf, combobox, wpf-controls, click, routed-events

I have a TextBlock which is over a ComboBox and I want the combobox popup (dropdown) apear when I click on it.

```
<Grid>
    <ComboBox Name="tstcmb" Height="27" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="29,92,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="131"  SelectedIndex="1"  >
       <ComboBoxItem>a</ComboBoxItem>
       <ComboBoxItem>aaaa</ComboBoxItem>
    </ComboBox>
    <TextBlock Text="skdkdkdk" Background="Green" Height="16" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="29,92,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="131" />
</Grid>
```

Is it possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set IsHitTestVisible="False"

```
<TextBlock IsHitTestVisible="False".../>
```

In that way the TextBlock doesn't intercept mouse clicks and allows them to be handled by the ComboBox underneath.